# converted_model.tflite does not encode a valid TensorFlowLite model: Could not open file_path. The model is not a valid Flatbuffer file

Tags: android, tensorflow, android-gradle-plugin, tensorflow-lite

I am trying to load `converted_tflite.tflite` from the assets directory.
It's giving me an error `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Contents of /file:/android_asset/converted_model.tflite does not encode a valid TensorFlowLite model: Could not open '/file:/android_asset/converted_model.tflite'.The model is not a valid Flatbuffer file`

```
File file = new File("file:///android_asset/converted_model.tflite");
        try (Interpreter interpreter = new Interpreter(file)) {
            interpreter.run(inputData, output);
            Log.d("TF LOG", output);
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
}
```

What I tried based on the stackoverflow answers

```
aaptOptions {
    noCompress "tflite"
}
```

tensoflow-lite nighty version

```
implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite:0.1.2-nightly'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used tensorflow-nighty build gradle version 0.1.2

```
    implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite:0.1.2-nightly'
```

To load the model

```
/** Memory-map the model file in Assets. */
private static MappedByteBuffer loadModelFile(AssetManager assets, String modelFilename)
        throws IOException {
    AssetFileDescriptor fileDescriptor = assets.openFd(modelFilename);
    FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(fileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor());
    FileChannel fileChannel = inputStream.getChannel();
    long startOffset = fileDescriptor.getStartOffset();
    long declaredLength = fileDescriptor.getDeclaredLength();
    return fileChannel.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, startOffset, declaredLength);
}
```

Comment: I tried this but got the error: `Could not find org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite-gpu:0.1.2-nightly.
Required by:
    project :app`

Answer (score 1):

As error indicates `model is not a valid Flatbuffer file`. In your implementation, model is as a `File`. It supposed to be convert to flatbuffer file as implemented below,

```
FileInputStream f_input_stream= new FileInputStream(new File("file:///android_asset/converted_model.tflite"));
FileChannel f_channel = f_input_stream.getChannel();
MappedByteBuffer tflite_model = f_channel.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, 0, f_channel .size());
```

And than you can use this `tflite_model` to create tflite interpreter as `New Interpreter(...)`.

Comment: still getting error ```Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ByteBuffer is not a valid flatbuffer model
        at org.tensorflow.lite.NativeInterpreterWrapper.createModelWithBuffer(Native Method)
        at org.tensorflow.lite.NativeInterpreterWrapper.<init>(NativeInterpreterWrapper.java:59)
        at org.tensorflow.lite.Interpreter.<init>(Interpreter.java:224)
        at org.tensorflow.lite.Interpreter.<init>(Interpreter.java:212)```

Comment: Can you update your question with tensorflow version? and part of script which throws this error.

Comment: ```implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite:0.1.2-nightly'``` Though, I have made it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the existing answers, if you have created the tflite model with latest Tensorflow version (2.4.0) and facing a similar issue, add the below line to dependencies of build.gradle file

```
implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite:2.4.0'
```

and use the function provided by @LalitSharma for loading the model from 'assets' directory.

Can find the most recent release here
https://bintray.com/google/tensorflow/tensorflow-lite