# Cannot import tensorflow lite model on android studio. This is not a valid TensorFlow Lite model file

Tags: android, android-studio, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I'm trying to import a tensorflow lite model into my android studio. I've followed the documentation all along. I have exported a correct tensorflow lite model with an extension .tflite on it but in android studio it says that it is an invalid file.

`This is not a valid TensorFlow Lite Model file.`

On the import window. I'm really confused why is this happening. I've searched through forums everywhere, they said it is because of my android studio is not 4.2. I've updated it but it still cannot work. I'm really stuck in this and don't know what to do. Can anyone who have experienced this problem share your solution? Or is there any possible ways to deploy my model into my android project? I've tried firebase ML kit but it says maximum limit is 40MB while my model is 160MB. Then its suggesting me to bundle the app into the local but then again the documentation is deprecated and so basically I can't use it.

Would really appreciate anyone's answer here

**UPDATE:**

Here's the public link to the tflite file that you can download https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1aGeg0SJHCsGT7yvkny-8ijPKGYZJqODE?usp=sharing

Comment: Does your tflite file contain metadata? Can you give a link to download the file and verify?

Comment: Hi @Farmaker ! Really appreciate you taking the time for answering me. Here's a google drive folder that has the tflite file in it. https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1aGeg0SJHCsGT7yvkny-8ijPKGYZJqODE?usp=sharing You can download it from there

Comment: I used [netron.app](netron.app) to view your file. It gives a string[1] as the input and a float32[1,21] as the output. Do you recognize anything from this info. Is it OK??? Check it for yourself at the above web link and tell me if this is OK.

Comment: @Farmaker yes that is absolutely correct. I'm inputting a string and gives a float with a size of [1,21] as the output. Did you find what was wrong in the tflite model that it cannot be imported to android studio?

Comment: I checked a little bit and I think it is an issue that has been raised recently with AS https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/45373. Please use this code for inference inside your Python notebook https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/inference#load_and_run_a_model_in_python and if everything runs correctly then you have to use the TensorFlow Lite API for inference currently until they fix the AS bug. You can find a lot of examples here to load the model and make inference inside android https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/examples or here https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/tutorials

Comment: I forwarded this to tflite team. If they come up with a solution I will get back to you.

Comment: @Farmaker Thanks a lot for your help.. Will also look for more solutions myself. Hoping to hear back from you!

Comment: This usually happens when the tflite model is compressed. Android Gradle plugin 4.1 and above adds tflite models to the noCompress list by default. See the instruction [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/inference_with_metadata/lite_support#import_gradle_dependency_and_other_settings) about how to add noCompress manually.

Comment: @LuWang I've tried that as well and it didn't work..

Comment: For now use the TensorFlow Lite API so not to lose time. I think your model did not have metadata so you have to write some boilerplate code even if AS imports it automatically or not. Also consider the size of the tflite file which is huge!!

Comment: @Farmaker Alright, I'll give it a try first with the TensorFlow Lite API. Thanks again for your help! I'll let you know what I did if it works.

Comment: No having metadata should be fine to AS. Is "This is not a valid TensorFlow Lite Model file" the exact error message? I didn't find this in our code base.

Comment: Also, seems like your model is a text classification model. If so, you can try Task Library [NLClassfier](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/inference_with_metadata/task_library/nl_classifier). Adding metadata is optional if you don't want to parse the labels automatically. But if you are interested in it, you can populate metadata using the [metadata writer library](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/convert/metadata_writer_tutorial#natural_language_classifiers). RegexTokenizerMd in create_for_inference is not needed, because your model takes a string as input. So you can just pass None for it.

Comment: @LuWang I've tried following the documentation. I implemented the gradle dependencies and everything but I can't get to call the objects like NLClassifier into my android project. I'm using Kotlin and its really hard to follow. Is there any documentations on how to use the NLClassifier in Kotlin?

Comment: @LuWang its also really hard to find any documentations on how to import the tflite file manually and how to call it in the code here. So I'm really blank on how to do the next steps...

Comment: You can simply use the [Java API](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/inference_with_metadata/task_library/nl_classifier#step_2_run_inference_using_the_api). AS can help you convert the code into Kotlin if you like.

Comment: About import the model manually, what you need to do is just to copy the .tflite model file to the assets directory of the Android module where the model will be run, which is documented in the section, [Step 1: Import Gradle dependency and other settings](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/inference_with_metadata/task_library/nl_classifier#step_1_import_gradle_dependency_and_other_settings). Let me know if it works.

Comment: @LuWang I have put the .`.tflite` model inside my assets directory, setup my app level `build.gradle` exactly like how it is written in the documentation and have copied and pasted the step 2 code from the documentation but it seems that the gradle dependencies have no effect because I can't even call the `NLCLassifierOptions` object as AS doesn't even recognize it!

Comment: Have you imported NLCLassifierOptions? Does NLClassifier work for you? Please see this [file](https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/blob/master/lite/examples/text_classification/android/lib_task_api/src/main/java/org/tensorflow/lite/examples/textclassification/client/TextClassificationClient.java) for an example of how to use NLClassifier.

Comment: @LuWang I cannot import it, by the time I typed in `import org.tensorflow.lite.text` the `text` part got red saying `Unresolved reference: text` while I have already put the `implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite-task-text:0.2.0` in my dependencies in my app level `build.gradle` and have already synced it.. There are no errors whatsoever when I synced it also.

Comment: Please try "import org.tensorflow.lite.task.text.nlclassifier.NLClassifier;" and "import org.tensorflow.lite.task.text.nlclassifier.NLCLassifierOptions.NLClassifierOptions;".  I remember Android Studio can help you auto complete import statement as well, i.e. hover your mouse over `NLClassifier` in your code, and press ENTER+Shift, but please double check if the short cut works on your machine.

Comment: Hi! Could you check out these below threads for answer too.    https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/47571#issuecomment-791598653   https://stackoverflow.com/a/66734683/11530462