# Not a valid tensorflow model

Tags: java, android, tensorflow, machine-learning, tflite

I have created a tensorflow lite model with metadata. But when I open this .tflite file in android studio it show that "Not a valid tensorflow model". What can be the problem and how to proceed for it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: See this related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56256478/converted-model-tflite-does-not-encode-a-valid-tensorflowlite-model-could-not-o/66734683#66734683